# Telerik Kendo DropDown sends the previous value to the Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have been working in ASP MVC (C#) razor Entity Framework project, Visual Studio 2012, that uses Telerik Kendo DropDown:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(run => run.Repair)
                                    .Name("Repair")
                                    .OptionLabel(RunStrings.Select)
                                    .DataTextField("Text")
                                    .DataValueField("Value")
                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetRepairCodes", "Run")
                                        )
                                    )
                                    .Value(myModel.Repair.ToString())
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50% !important;" })
                                    .Events( e => e.Change("RepairDropDown_OnChange")))
```

The DropDown sends its value to the Controller, in the object outcomeModel. The code of the Controller is:

```
public ActionResult OutcomeEdit(OutcomeModel outcomeModel, string previous, string next, string finish)
        {
            Run run = Session["Run"] as Run;
            if (run == null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                outcomeModel.CopyToRun(run);

                Repository myRepo = new Repository();
                myRepo.UpdateOutcome(run);

                // now update the Organ failure column
                string organFailureString = string.Empty;
                if (run.Discontinuation == Discontinuation.DiedOrganFailure && ModelState["OrganFailureType"] != null)
                {
                    organFailureString = outcomeModel.DecodeOrganFailureFromString(ModelState["OrganFailureType"].Value.AttemptedValue).ToString();
                    myRepo.UpdateOrganFailureValue(run.RunId, organFailureString);
                }
                else
                {
                    run.OrganFailure = null;
                    myRepo.UpdateOutcome(run);
                }

                /***
                * This will redirect user to a selected tab
                */
                string jumptToTab = Request.Form["JumpToTab"];
                if (jumptToTab != "-1")
                {
                    TabIndex gotoindex = (TabIndex)Convert.ToInt32(jumptToTab);
                    TempData["TabIndex"] = (int)gotoindex;
                    return RedirectToAction(GiveLinkToPage(gotoindex));
                }
                // continue normally

                // Find which command was selected (non-null parameter)
                var selection = (new[] { previous, next, finish })
                    .Select((item, index) => new { ItemName = item, Position = index })
                    .First(x => x.ItemName != null);

                TabIndex currentTab = TabIndex.SeverityScores;

                LinkDirection command = LinkDirection.Finish;
                if (selection.Position == 0) { command = LinkDirection.Previous; }
                if (selection.Position == 1) { command = LinkDirection.Next; }
                if (selection.Position == 2) { command = LinkDirection.Finish; }

                TempData.Keep("TabIndex");
                TempData["TabIndex"] = this.GiveFutureTabIndex(command, currentTab);

                string link = this.GiveFutureLink(command, currentTab);
                return RedirectToAction(link);
            }

            return View(outcomeModel);
        }
```

But, in outcomeModel, in Repair property, in debugger I always see the previous value of the DropDown, not that value which is chosen. I cannot find the reason why. So, I decided to set the value of the DropDown by force of in the JavaScript OnChange event of the DropDown:

```
<script>
        function RepairDropDown_OnChange(e) {        
        console.log('RepairDropDown_OnChange');
        console.log('Model ' + e.model);
        console.log('Container ' + e.container.find('#Repair').length);

        e.model.set("Repair", e.container.find('#Repair').val());
    }

</script>
```

But, in Console of the Browser I see that e.model is undefined. How can I solve the bug? Thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE** 
OutcomeModel is :

```
public class OutcomeModel : RunModelBase
    {
        #region Construction

        public OutcomeModel() { }

        public OutcomeModel(Run run)
        {
            if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<DateTimeOffset, DateTime>() == null)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<DateTimeOffset, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<DateTimeOffsetConverter>();
            }

            if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Run, OutcomeModel>() == null)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<Run, OutcomeModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.UniqueId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Patient.UniqueId))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Birthdate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Patient.Birthdate))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Sex, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Patient.Sex))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Race, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Patient.Race))
                    .IgnoreAllNonExisting();

                Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            }
            Mapper.Map(run, this);
        }

        #endregion Construction

        #region Properties

        public string OrganFailureType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Discontinuation", Description = "DiscontinuationDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [UIHint("Enum")]
        public Discontinuation? Discontinuation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OrganFailure", Description = "OrganFailureDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public OrganFailure OrganFailure { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DischargedAlive", Description = "DischargedAliveDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public bool? DischargedAlive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DischargeLocation", Description = "DischargeLocationDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [UIHint("Enum")]
        public DischargeLocation? DischargeLocation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ExtubationDate", Description = "ExtubationDateDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]
        [CompareValues("IntubationDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ExtubationDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [CompareValues("AdmitDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ExtubationDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public DateTime? ExtubationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DischargeDate", Description = "DischargeDateDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]
        [CompareValues("IntubationDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DischargeDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [CompareValues("AdmitDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DischargeDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public DateTime? DischargeDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DeathDate", Description = "DeathDateDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}")]
        [CompareValues("IntubationDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DeathDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        [CompareValues("AdmitDate", CompareValues.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, ErrorMessageResourceName = "DeathDateError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Repair", Description = "RepairDescription", ResourceType = typeof(RunStrings))]
        public short? Repair { get; set; }

        // Following properties are in model for validation, but are not copied/persisted

        public DateTime? AdmitDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? IntubationDate { get; set; }

        #endregion Properties
```

**UPDATE2**
myModel is:

```
ELSORegistry.DataAccess.Run myModel = Session["run"] as ELSORegistry.DataAccess.Run;
```

Comment: Using javascript is not necessary. Do you have any other inputs in the view for `Repair`? (and remove `.Name("Repair")` and `.Value(myModel.Repair.ToString())` from the helper - NEVER set those attributes when using the strongly typed methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and help. I don't have any other inputs for `Repair` in the view. I tried to remove `.Name("Repair")` and `.Value(myModel.Repair.ToString())` but everything is the same, I have the bug again.

Comment: Its something else in your code causing the problem. Show your model. And what is `myModel`?

Comment: Please see UPDATE and UPDATE2 in my question.

Comment: Nothing obvious that wrong in the model (although its a bit strange why you would have had `.Value(myModel.Repair.ToString())` - do you really have another variable `myModel` in the view? and why?). Are the other properties of the model binding correctly?

Comment: I used myModel to show the other things on the page. For `Repair` I hoped if I put `Model.Repair.ToString()` it will solve my problem, but it didn't.

Comment: The other properties of the model binding correctly.